# Multiply n to m rows then add them all together

Tags: python, pandas

I need to multiply all n rows from different columns and then add them with the next n rows until end. Example below:

```
n1 n2
x1 x2
.  .
.  .
m1 m2
```

I need to perform:

```
n1*n2 + x1*x2 + ... + m1*m2
```

Comment: Are these all numbers? Then convert it to a NumPy array, which will makes things easier or clearer. Use e.g. `df.to_numpy()` for that. See `numpy.prod` and `numpy.sum`.

Comment: @00 yes, all of them are integers

Comment: FYI: if there are two columns, this operation is called a "dot" or "scalar" product of those two (column) vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dot.html) for matrix multiplication:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col1':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'col2':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
})

out = df['col1'].dot(df['col2'])
print (out)
109
```

What is same like multiple and `sum`:

```
out = df['col1'].mul(df['col2']).sum()
print (out)
109
```